# Why does itertools.dropwhile only work once with a list?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I cannot understand the following behavior of itertools.dropwhile().
Let's say, I have a list:

`numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]`

I overwrite like that:

`numbers = list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: sum(numbers[0:x]) <=7, numbers))`

The sum of values [1,2,3] is less than 7, so I expect they will be dropped.
And indeed, the output is:

```
>>>numbers
[4, 5]
```

I repeat:

`numbers = list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: sum(numbers[0:x]) <=7, numbers))`

I expect that output should be `[5]` now. But instead, I see again:

```
>>>numbers
[4, 5]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Because the first time you run it, it changes the value of the object associated with the variable name `numbers`.

Comment: I am surprised that it doesn't happen the second time

Comment: your predicate isn't doing what you think it is doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't do what you think it does. The callable that you hand to `dropwhile` gets elements, not indices.

The reason the result in the first call is `[4, 5]` because:

- `sum(numbers[0:1]) <= 7`
- `sum(numbers[0:2]) <= 7`
- `sum(numbers[0:3]) <= 7`

are all lower or equal to 7.

In the second call, both `numbers[0:4]` and `numbers[0:5]` are just the entire list, whose sum is always 9.

---

You can instead `dropwhile` over an enumeration:

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> numbers = [element for i, element in itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: sum(numbers[0:x[0]+1]) <= 7, enumerate(numbers))]
>>> numbers
[4, 5]
>>> numbers = [element for i, element in itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: sum(numbers[0:x[0]+1]) <= 7, enumerate(numbers))]
>>> numbers
[5]
>>> numbers = [element for i, element in itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: sum(numbers[0:x[0]+1]) <= 7, enumerate(numbers))]
>>> numbers
[]
```